# Why Do i get a MaxListenersExceededWarning when trying to create a react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-router

I am curious as to why I get a `MaxListenersExceededWarning` yet I haven`t even started writing my code yet.

So I am trying out **react-native** and **expo**, and I am looking at the documentation which suggests that I use this command to create my project:

```
npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@49
```

Thats when I get this warning multiple times:

```
(node:44064) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

The project is eventually created and continue with everything else.

I know this is usually caused by mismatched bound event listener functions, but I haven`t written any functions yet. Is this a bug in my installation(s) or something else I should be worried about.

I tried a different command and it worked without the warning:

```
npx create-expo-app
```

I also tried another command which also worked without the warning:

```
npx create-expo-app@latest --example with-router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`m embarrassed by this, but this whole problem goes away when you switch to a better internet connection. There you have it, the fun side of being a dev in a third world country :|